# Multiple Parameters in UDF in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, table-valued-parameters

I am trying to established a Function to have multiple parameters as see below @SITENAME, @MARKET and @DATE.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Platform_Parser]
(
  @SITENAME NVARCHAR(2000) NULL
  ,@MARKET NVARCHAR(2000) NULL
  ,@DATE Date NULL
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
  CASE
WHEN @SITENAME LIKE '%GOOGLE%' AND @DATE < '2022-01-01' AND @MARKET IN ('FR','DE') THEN 'TWITTER'
    WHEN @SITENAME LIKE '%GOOGLE%' AND @DATE < '2022-01-01' AND @MARKET = 'UK' THEN 'YOUTUBE'
    ELSE 'Unclassified'
  END
END
GO
```

This is the data in [dbo].[MyTable]

| SiteName | Market | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GOOGLE | FR | 11/11/2021 |
| YAHOO | FR | 09/05/2021 |
| GOOGLE | DE | 03/07/2021 |
| GOOGLE | UK | 05/12/2021 |
| GOOGLE | UK | 05/05/2022 |
| YAHOO | DE | 03/02/2022 |
| YAHOO | UK | 21/03/2022 |

However, when I try to implement the function in a different view as below I experience the error that I have too many arguments.

```
SELECT 

[dbo].[Platform_Parser]([SiteName],[Market],[Date])   AS [Publisher]
,[Market]  AS [Market]
,[Date] AS [Date]

FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

Result should be as below

| Publisher | Market | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TWITTER | FR | 11/11/2021 |
| YAHOO | FR | 09/05/2021 |
| TWITTER | DE | 03/07/2021 |
| YOUTUBE | UK | 05/12/2021 |
| GOOGLE | UK | 05/05/2022 |
| YAHOO | DE | 03/02/2022 |
| YAHOO | UK | 21/03/2022 |

Comment: If you aren't using SQL Server 2019, I would suggest against a multi-line scalar function anyway. As for Table Type parameters, you *can* use these against functions, but I doubt it's the way you want to; you don't pass a *table name* to it, you would need to define a variable of the appropriate user defined table `TYPE` in `INSERT` the rows into it. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here; i suspect what you have are asking here is an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, initially I had a working Function that determined the Platform with a singular parameter of "@SITENAME" however then had to further parameters to determine these Platforms using "Date" and "Market" as well as SITENAME.  That is my main problem

Comment: That doesn't really explain the *actual* problem you want to solve. Especially when you want to pass a table type parameter to the function, yet the function doesn't even have a `FROM`, so having a table type doesn't fit with the current design. You need to *explain* in detail, the problem you are trying to solve. Provide sample data (in a consumable format) and expected results.

Comment: Sorry @Larnu, first post on Stack, I have updated the initial post hopefully to simplify the problem.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=74270978eca9ea7754fe5f8bd545af9f). Can you provide an [mre]?

Comment: I have added in My Table before and after the function. Is this sufficient?

Comment: That's not a [mre], no.

Comment: I'm not seeing the error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9ce5e9bd18d609dfc04e732350f17fc

Answer (score -1):

You can use your function in queries with different tables, you don't need to include the table name in the function.

For your example, you can write something like this:

```
select [dbo].[Platform_Parser]([SiteName],[Market],[Date]) 
from [dbo].[ThisTable]
```

Just make sure `[SiteName]`, `[Market]`, and `[Date]` are columns in `[dbo].[ThisTable]`; or, if not, pass the column names as the function parameters.